# npm run start ends with a lerna ERR

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, lerna, npm-start

I have cloned and installed the packages of a repo I have to work on at my company. I came across multiple installation issues, mainly due to VPN, but I managed to bypass that in the end. So I installed all the packages and now, when I am trying to open it up with npm run start, I get this error.

```
yds: > yds@1.9.0 build:less:print
yds: > lessc --source-map-inline --autoprefix="last 2 versions" --inline-svg="encode=true" src/less/print.less dist/yarn-print.css
yds: > yds@1.9.0 build:less:utils
yds: > lessc --source-map-inline --autoprefix="last 2 versions" --inline-svg="encode=true" src/less/utils.less dist/yarn-utils.css
yds: > yds@1.9.0 build:scss
yds: > npm run clean:scss && npm run build:scss:variables && npm run build:scss:themes
yds: > yds
@1.9.0 clean:scss
yds: > del src/scss
yds: Parameter format not correct - "scss".
lerna ERR! npm run build exited 1 in 'yds'
```

I honestly have no idea what this is about, I tried Googling it but I didn't find a similar issue.

package.json

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "repo URL"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10",
    "npm": ">= 5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "lerna bootstrap --no-ci",
    "setup:ci": "lerna bootstrap --ci",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "lerna run start --parallel",
    "clean": "del docs && lerna run clean --stream",
    "build": "npm run doc && lerna run build --stream",
    "build:min": "npm run doc && lerna run build:min --stream",
    "lint": "lerna run lint --stream",
    "doc": "lerna run doc --stream",
    "test": "lerna run test --stream",
    "lerna:exec": "lerna exec",
    "lerna:run": "lerna run",
    "lerna:publish": "lerna exec -- safe-publish --registry=URL"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del-cli": "3.0.1",
    "lerna": "3.20.2",
    "safe-publish": "1.2.1"
  },
```

Comment: Could you present your package.json file ? Please.. ;-)

Comment: Added in main post. @MarioG8